# Comparing the value pointed by a pointer

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Let's pretend that the variable `a` is placed in the address `0xDEADBEEF` and it's value is `42`.
How can I compare the value of `a` (`42`) with another int?

Currently I have (intel syntax):

```
mov rax, 0xDEADBEEF;
mov rdi, 1;
cmp [rax], rdi;
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Does it fail or break?

Comment: @KerrekSB no, but it isn't either doing what I expect, and I'm not sure if the bug is because of this code or because of something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little endian processors (like most modern desktop ones) arrange values in memory backwards. For example if the value at 0xDEADBEEF is `42`, aka `0x0000002A`, then it will be stored as

```
2A 00 00 00
```

You can force how many bytes the `cmp [rax], rdi;` command compares by prepending byte/word/double. For example in nasm

```
cmp BYTE [rax], rdi;
```

would compare only the first byte pointed at by the pointer `rax`.

Check your assembler's documentation for exact syntax. Also check how many bytes your assembler compares with `cmp` command by default.

---

**Edit:**
Disregard everything I wrote above.

Since you your question is tagged `x86-64` I assume your program is 64 bit.

`rdi` is 8 bytes long. Your code does everything right IF the value at `0xDEADBEEF` is 8 bytes long as well:

```
2A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Otherwise if only the first 4 or 2 or  bytes set to correct value, your program may or may not work correctly. For example if the value at `0xDEADBEEF` is 4 bytes long, then it will look like this

```
2A 00 00 00 ?? ?? ?? ??
```

The rest of the memooryy will contain some other random information. Your program will have the worst kind of bug - the one that occurs randomly. The cmp instruction will still compare 8 bytes, as `rdi` is 8 bytes long.

And to answer your comment to Gunner's question (as I don't have privilege to comment):

```
mov rax, [0xDEADBEEF]
cmp rax, 1
```

IS the same as

```
mov rax, 0xDEADBEEF
cmp [rax], 1
```

Comment: mov-ing the value of ```0xDEADBEEF``` inside rax will make rax to be ```24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00```. And mov-ing 1 into rdi, will make rdi to be ```01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00```. Comparing those values as word, dword or qword should return the same result, right?

Comment: @alexandernst Yes, `rax` will point to `2A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. Also there was a type in my post - wrote 24 instead of 2A. Values are stored in natural order in registers, so `rdi` will be `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01`. Yes, the size of operands shouldn't matter - disregard my original post :)

Comment: Indeed, I thought about something fishy with that 4bytes int into 8 bytes register... (because, yeah, 0xDEADBEEF points to an int). I guess I should move to eax instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Which assembler? For gas, assuming `.intel_syntax noprefix`:

```
    cmp QWORD PTR ds:0xdeadbeef, 1
```

Note that the `0xdeadbeef` will be sign extended. You may prefer to be explicit and include the `ff`s to make that clear.

Usually you won't need to specify `ds:` because you will be referring to a label and the assembler will handle things. That is:

```
    cmp DWORD PTR [foo], 1
    cmp DWORD PTR foo, 1      # same thing
```

Answer (score -1):

You are `mov`ing the value `0xDEADBEEF` into `rax`, instead you need to **L** oad the **E** ffective **A** ddress into `rax`

Not sure of your Assembler, but in NASM:

```
lea rax, [SomeAddress]
```

Or:

```
mov rax, [SomeAddress]
```

Comment: Why? I really want to get the *value* of ```0xDEADBEEF``` inside ```rax```. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As per what you said: "Let's pretend that the variable a is placed in the address 0xDEADBEEF and it's value is 42" and your title: "Comparing the value pointed by a pointer".

Comment: Isn't ```mov rax, [0xDEADBEEF]``` the same as ```mov rax, 0xDEADBEEF``` and then ```cmp [rax], 1```?

Comment: No, `mov rax, 0xDEADBEEF` is moving the value `0xDEADBEEF` into `rax`, where `mov rax, [0xDEADBEEF]` means, move whats at the address `0xDEADBEEF` into `rax`.  Do you want the box - `0xDEADBEEF` or what's in the [box] (pointed to by) [0xDEADBEEF]`?  Have you tried using []?

Comment: I still can't see how ```mov rax, [0xDEADBEEF]; cmp rax, 1;``` is not the same as ```mov rax, 0xDEADBEED; cmp [rax], 1```. I mean, I'm using ```[]``` in both ways, right?